# How to select number questions in exsheets with some rules?

Tags: exsheets

I have some questions in Database.tex (6 questions).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = subsection ,
  counter-format = \thesection.qu.,
  headings=runin
}
\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam, name=Problem}
\begin{document}
\section{Random}
\subsection{The first way}
\includequestions[random={2}]{Database_English.tex}
\subsection{Second way}
\subsection{Odd label}
\includequestions[IDs={q1,q3,q5}]{Database_English.tex}
\subsection{Even label}
\includequestions[IDs={q2,q4,q6}]{Database_English.tex}
\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

Database.tex

```
\begin{question}[ID=q1]
The question was labeled q1.
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
Solution.
\end{solution}
\begin{question}[ID=q2]
The question was labeled q2.
\end{question}
\begin{question}[ID=q3]
The question was labeled q3.
\end{question}

\begin{question}[ID=q4]
The question was labeled q4.
\end{question}

\begin{question}[ID=q5]
The question was labeled q5.
\end{question}

\begin{question}[ID=q6]
The question was labeled q6.
\end{question}
```

Now I select random with following  rules.

1. The questions were labeled with odd numbers. I tried

   \includequestions[IDs={q1,q3,q5}]{Database.tex}
2. The questions were labeled with even numbers. I tried

   \includequestions[IDs={q2,q4,q6}]{Database.tex}
3. selected 2 questions

   \includequestions[random={2}]{Database.tex}

[image]

My problem is If I have 100 questions. How can I select

1. Questions 1, 3, 5, ..., 99?
2. Questions 2, 4, 6, ..., 100?
3. Questions 3, 6, 9, ..., 3k?
4. Questions from 1 to 30?

Comment: The ranges you ask at the bottom of your question are not random at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't solve my problem with `exsheets`. I tried with `xsim`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{xsim,pgffor}
\usepackage{needspace}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{runin}
{%
\par\vspace{\baselineskip}
\Needspace * {2\baselineskip}
\noindent
\textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
\GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{#1}} %
\GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
\marginpar{%
\PropertyValue
\GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{+\PropertyValue}%
\,\IfExerciseGoalSingularTF{points}
 {\XSIMtranslate{point}}
{\XSIMtranslate{points}}%
 }%
 }%
 }
 {}
\xsimsetup{
exercise/within=section ,
exercise/template=runin,
solution/template=runin,
solution/print = true,
exercise/the-counter = \thesection.\arabic{exercise}.}
\DeclareExerciseCollection{exam}

\begin{document}

\collectexercises{exam}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q1]
  1
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
  1
\end{solution}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q2]
  2
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q3]
  3
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q4]
  4
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q5]
  5
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q6]
  6
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q7]
  7
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q8]
  8
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ID=q9]
  9
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[ID=q10]
  10
\end{exercise}
\collectexercisesstop{exam}

\section{All labels}
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,10}{
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\x}}
}

\section{Some labels}
\subsection{Type 1}
\foreach \x in {3,4,...,10}{
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\x}}
}
\subsection{Type 2, any order}
\foreach \x in {9,7,6,3}{
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\x}}
}
\section{Odd labels}
\foreach \x in {1,3,...,10}{
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\x}}
}
\section{Even labels}
\foreach \x in {2,4,...,10}{
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\x}}
}
\section{Random}
\subsection{Firt time}
\printrandomexercises[collection=exam]{2}
\subsection{Second time}
\printrandomexercises[collection=exam]{2}
\section{Answers}
\printsolutions
\end{document}
```

[image]